# postgres extension pg_background on debian

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I have several servers where I need to install postgres 9.6 with the extension pg_background. But this extension is not in the "postgresql-contrib" package. 
The extension source and instructions are here:
https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background

The point is that according to the instructions it is necessary to download and compile the source code on every server.

Is there a way to "compile" the source code just once obtaining some kind of archive and then copy and install it to all servers?.
I mean, I would like not to have to download the source code and compile it on every server.